# forward mapping vs inverse mapping

Tags: computer-vision, opencl, gpu

I have to do a gpu implementation (opencl) of a image mapping.

I seem to remember having read somewhere that forward mapping is better suited for a parallel implementation, why is that?

And do anyone have some example code on how to do these mappings (preferably on the gpu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the intuitive choice for a parallel implementation would be an inverse, not forward, mapping.

Consider instances where several source pixels map to a single destination pixel. In forward mapping, if each source pixel were evaluated as a distinct work-item, you would have to implement some kind of synchronization on the destination pixel to co-ordinate the multiple writes. In inverse mapping there is no synchronization overhead, since it is guaranteed that only one work-item writes to each pixel.

Example inverse-mapping kernel code, leveraging OpenCL's image2d_t and sampler_t concepts for image manipulation:

```
__kernel void warp(__read_only image2d_t srcImage,
                   __write_only image2d_t dstImage,
                   sample_r sampler)
{
    int2 dstCoords = (int2){ get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)};
    int2 srcCoords = my_warp_func_inverse(dstCoords);
    float4 srcPixel = read_imagef(srcImage, sampler, srcCoords);
    write_imagef(dstImage, dstCoords, srcPixel);
}
```

Of course there are exceptions where forward mapping might be preferable. For example if you had a very large source image and a small destination image, then forward mapping would allow you to split the source image into segments, then divide them amongst work-items or work-groups with the segment data cached in __private or __local address spaces. Without prior knowledge of the mapping function, an inverse mapping might need to access any part of the source image, which potentially restricts you to __global memory.